# Not fetching all entities in OneToMany relationship

Tags: spring, spring-data

I have used spring, spring data and mysql.I have `PersonEntity` and `EmailEntity`. There is `OneToMany` relationship between them ie one person has many emails.

Person Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "person")
public class PersonEntity
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "personid")
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "id")
  private List<EmailEntity> emails;
}
```

Email Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "email")
public class EmailEntity
{

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "emailid")
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "personid")
  private PersonEntity personEntity;
}
```

I fetched Person data using spring data

```
PersonEntity personEntity = personDAO.findOne(id);
```

I have more than one emails for a person in database.
When I debug code, `PersonEntity` contains only one `EmailEntity` though there are more than two EmailEntities in list.

Where it is getting wrong?
Please make me correct if wrong?

Comment: `mappedBy` should link to the property holding the reverse side of the relation. In your case that is probably `personEntity`, not `id`.

Comment: Did fixing that little mistake solved your issue? If so, I will post it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Annotation parameter `mappedBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html#mappedBy%28%29) should link to the property holding the reverse side of the relation. In your case that is `personEntity`, not `id`.

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade=javax.persistence.CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="personEntity")
private List<EmailEntity> emails;
```

What have probably happened in your configuration is that the emails were fetched by matching their `id` to the `id` or your person.